# how to play an audio from directory file in xcode?

Tags: ios

i'm trying to design audio streaming app everything is working, but i don't know how to download audio file to the device and read it afterword.

> 1. **Download** audio to **document directory**.
> 2. **play** it back from **document directory**.

Added code:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"evet.mp3"];
// UIImage *cellImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
NSError *error;
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_objectData error:&error];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: What have you tried? where did you get stuck? You question now looks like a code request which is frowned up and might get you down voted.

Comment: i can download the audio into the device, but i can't play it back from the directory

Comment: Add the code that isn't working.

Comment: NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  \n
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"evet.mp3"];
    //        UIImage *cellImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    
    NSError *error;
    NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
    
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_objectData error:&error];
    [audioPlayer play];

Comment: Check that your file is properly downloaded with proper extension or not

Comment: yes, it's downloaded an i checked on that, but still not playing. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted try this.

Change

```
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_objectData error:&error];
```

to this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
```

AVAudioPlayer wants a URL object (which needs to be a local URL not a remote web address, hence `fileURLWithPath:`) not the data itself.

You were trying to give the NSData itself to the audio player.

Comment: Add this line after `[audioPlayer play];`.     `NSLog(@"error: %@", error);` and post what it says the error is.

Comment: it says the following :-(
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)"

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your audio file in document directory

```
- (NSString *)getCacheDirectoryPathForAudio:(NSString *)filePath
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", filePath]]; //add

    return fullPath;
}
```

Initiate player with file path

```
NSString *pathToSaveAudioString = [self getCacheDirectoryPathForAudio:@“filename”];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSaveAudioString];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathToSaveAudioString];
    if (fileExists) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        [self.player setDelegate:self];
        if(!self.player)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            NSLog(@“File Not Exist: %@");
    }
```

and play it using

```
  [self.player play];
```

Use Delegate methods to check status

```
#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

For more details follow 
http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/10/01/tutorial-playing-audio-with-avaudioplayer/

Answer (score 0):

I have simple code

```
NSData *D = [self FindDatafromDocument:@"ASDF"];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:D error:nil];
[player setDelegate:self];
[player play];
```

**Method**

```
- (NSData *)FindDatafromDocument:(NSString *)Name {
    NSData *IMG;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[Utility getDocumentDirectory] error:&error];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",Name];
    NSArray *ArrImages = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *Doc =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    for (NSString *imageName in ArrImages) {
        if ([imageName rangeOfString:@".caf"].location != NSNotFound) {
            IMG = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",Doc,imageName]];
        }
    }
    return IMG;
}
```